# How can I update fields on a newly submitted form response in the Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Form and Sheet that I am working with.  When the user submits the form, I have code in the OnFormSubmit of the Sheet that runs.  Using an ID that they submit, I am able to lookup data in a second tab of that sheet and email that to someone.

I would like to add those values which I looked up to the response sheet.  Is this possible?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) 
{

  var myRange = e.range;
  sendEmail(myRange);

}

function sendEmail(submitRange) {

  // FETCH SPREADSHEET VALUES//
  var values = submitRange.getValues();
  var row = values[0];

  //WRITE FOUND VALUES TO EMAIL
  var svTimeStamp = row[0];  //A
  var svProjectManager = row[4]; //Update manually  //E
  var svClient = row[5]; //Update manually  //F

  //PREP LOOKUP VALUE SHEET
  var mySpreadSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('--SheetId---');
  var myLookupsTab = mySpreadSheetFile.getSheetByName("KMB Lookups");


  //In Column 6 find value for Project Number
  var projColumn = 6;
  var projectNumbers = myLookupsTab.getRange(2, projColumn, myLookupsTab.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  var rowIndex = projectNumbers.findIndex(svProjectID); //Row Index - 2

  //Get value for column 7
  var clntColumn = 7;
  var clntRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, clntColumn);
  var clntValue = clntRange.getValues();

  //I don't think I can update 'Values' from 'submitRange, so I open the sheet
  var myData = mySpreadSheetFile.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var newestData = myData.getRange(2, 1, myData.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  //FIND THE RECORD VIA MATCHING THE TIMESTAMP
  var rowNewDataIndex = newestData.findIndex(svTimeStamp); //Row Index - 2
  //UPDATE THE SHEET @ Rowindex, column 5
  myData.getRange(rowNewDataIndex+2, 5).setValue(clntValue);
```

I am expecting the cell to be updated with the lookup value.  The value of rowNewDataIndex is -14 each time.  I guess the row hasn't been written yet...

EDIT: I think the problem is because of a mismatch of formats:

```
RANGE: Mon Oct 21 2019 15:24:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
SHEET: Mon Oct 21 16:07:52 GMT-04:00 2019
```

This looks like it may work:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(svTimeStamp, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'E MMM dd k:mm:ss zZ yyyy');
formattedDate = formattedDate.toString().replace("EDT","GMT");
formattedDate = formattedDate.toString().replace("-0500","-05:00");
formattedDate = formattedDate.toString().replace("-0400","-04:00");
```

Then I can search the existing spreadsheet for that value.

Comment: You don't really need to as you can just get them directly from the event object of the onFormSubmit trigger.  It's either e.values or e.namedValues. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) You can add data to the sheet but I wouldn't recommend it.  It would just leave it alone and store the extra stuff on another sheet.

Comment: I didn't explain it thoroughly.  I'm already grabbing the value from e.values.  I need to compare that to the spreadsheet so I can add additional values.  It needs to be the same sheet because the sheet will be imported into a database and having to manually move or run something that combines them is an extra step I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sanitized copy of the files you are working on?

Comment: How do I get you a copy of the form and sheet?

Comment: Will post sanitized code as an answer.  Hopefully that is okay and the editors don't edit me.  :)

Comment: Follow this guide to share the files: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Thanks.  I actually got it to work by splitting my range into an array which changed the date format and now it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sanitized code.  I was able to match the dates by sending the range to an array.  Go figure.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) 
{
  var myRange = e.range;
  sendEmail(myRange);
}

function sendEmail(submitRange) {

  // FETCH SPREADSHEET //
  var values = submitRange.getValues();
  var row = values[0];

  //WRITE FOUND VALUES TO EMAIL
  var svProjectManager = row[4]; //E
  var svClient = row[5]; //F

  // EXTRACT VALUES //
  var svTimeStamp = row[0];  //A
  var svInitials = row[1];  //B
  var svProjectID = row[2];  //C


  //LOOKUP KMB PROJECT NUMBER IN SHEET: "New - KMB Design Visit Closeout (Responses)" TAB: "KMB Lookups"
  var mySpreadSheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('---Spreadsheet ID---');
  var myLookupsTab = mySpreadSheetFile.getSheetByName("KMB Lookups");

  //TODO - Need to code column numbers by looking for column-- column order may change.
  //In Column 5 'KMB Project ID' find record where value = svProjectID
  var projColumn = 5;
  var projectNumbers = myLookupsTab.getRange(2, projColumn, myLookupsTab.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  var rowIndex = projectNumbers.findIndex(svProjectID); //Row Index - 2

  //Get value for column named 'Client Assigning this Work' col 7
  var clntColumn = 7;
  var clntRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, clntColumn);
  var clntValue = clntRange.getValues();

  //Get value for column named 'Site Address'  col 28
  var addrColumn = 28;
  var addrRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, addrColumn);
  var addrValue = addrRange.getValues();

  //Get value for column named 'KMB Project Manager' col 11
  var pmgrColumn = 11; 
  var pmgrRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, pmgrColumn);
  var pmgrValue = pmgrRange.getValues();


  //GET SITETRACKER IDS AND WRITE TO SPREADSHEET
  console.log('Writing to spreadsheet');
  var IdColumn = 1; //Hearing Results
  var IDRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, IdColumn);
  var nameIdValue = IDRange.getValues();
  console.log(nameIdValue);

  IdColumn = 2; 
  var IDRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, IdColumn);
  var IdSiteNameValue = IDRange.getValues();
  console.log(IdSiteNameValue);

  IdColumn = 3; 
  var IDRange = myLookupsTab.getRange(rowIndex+2, IdColumn);
  var IdProjectIDValue = IDRange.getValues();
  console.log(IdProjectIDValue);

  console.log('Form Timestamp: '+svTimeStamp);


      //Update myData where field TimeStamp = svTimeStamp.  Set Name Id, Id Site Name, & Id Project Id  [FUZZLE]
  var myData = mySpreadSheetFile.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var newestData = myData.getRange(2, 1, myData.getLastRow()).getValues().toString(); //This is the TimeStamp column values without header
  newestData = newestData.split(",");
  console.log(newestData);
  var rowNewDataIndex = newestData.findIndex(svTimeStamp); //Row Index - 2
  console.log('Row to update = '+rowNewDataIndex);

  myData.getRange(rowNewDataIndex+2, 33).setValue(nameIdValue);
  myData.getRange(rowNewDataIndex+2, 34).setValue(IdSiteNameValue);
  myData.getRange(rowNewDataIndex+2, 35).setValue(IdProjectIDValue);


  var svSiteAddress = addrValue;  //D
  var svProjectManager = pmgrValue; //E
  var svClient = clntValue;  //F

  var svNOCNeeded = row[6];  //G
  var svNOCInCode = row[7];  //H
  var svNOCOutCode = row[8];  //I
  var svPurpose = row[9];  //J
  var svDVStatus = row[10];  //K
  var svWhyIncompleteDV = row[11];  //L
  var svFDNYReq = row[12];  //M
  var svFDNYStatus = row[13];  //N
  var svFDNYWhyNot = row[14];  //O
  var svLPCNeeded = row[15];  //P
  var svLPCStatusPhotos = row[16];  //Q
  var svLPCStatusRevisit = row[17];  //R
  var svDesignRevisitNeeded = row[18];  //S
  var svWhyRevisitPROBE = row[19];  //T
  var svWhyRevisitSTRUCT = row[20];  //U
  var svWhyRevisitELEC = row[21];  //V
  var svWhyRevisitPLUM = row[22];  //W
  var svWhyRevisitWIRE = row[23];  //X
  var svWhyRevisitOTHER = row[24];  //Y
  var svStructuralReview = row[25];  //Z
  var svStructuralReviewWhy = row[26];  //AA
  var svVisitComplete = row[27];  //AB
  var svWhyIncompleteSV = row[28];  //AC
  var svProvideAccessInfo = row[29];  //AD
  var svComments = row[30];  //AE
  var svHearingResults = row[31];  //AF

  // PREPARE EMAIL //
  var emailBody = "";  //Format using variables set

  //BUILD EMAIL BODY
  emailBody="<h3><u>Site Information</u></h3>"
  emailBody+="<p><strong>KMB Project Number:&nbsp;</strong>"+svProjectID+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p><strong>Site Address:&nbsp;</strong>"+svSiteAddress+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p><strong>Project Manager:&nbsp;</strong>"+svProjectManager+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p><strong>Client Assigning Work:&nbsp;</strong>"+svClient+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p><strong>Design Visit Type:&nbsp;</strong>"+svPurpose+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";

  //NOC SECTION
  if (svNOCNeeded == "Yes")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>NOC Code Entry</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>NOC In Code:&nbsp;"+svNOCInCode+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>NOC Out Code:&nbsp;"+svNOCOutCode+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //DESIGN VISIT STATUS SECTION
  if (svPurpose == "Design Visit")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>Design Visit Status</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>"+svDVStatus+"</p>";

    if(svDVStatus == "Not Completed")
    {
      emailBody+="<p>Reason: "+svWhyIncompleteDV+"</p>";
    }
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //FDNY SECTION
  if (svFDNYReq != "")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>FDNY</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>Required:&nbsp;"+svFDNYReq+"</p>";

    if(svFDNYReq == "Required")
    {
      emailBody+="<p>Info Status Gathering:&nbsp;"+svFDNYStatus+"</p>";
    }
    else
    {
      emailBody+="<p>Reason:&nbsp;"+svFDNYWhyNot+"</p>";
    }
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //LPC SECTION
  if (svLPCNeeded != "")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>LPC&nbsp;</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>Needed:&nbsp;"+svLPCNeeded+"</p>";
    if (svLPCNeeded == "Yes")
    {
      emailBody+="<h4>Status</h4>";
      emailBody+="<p>LPC Photos Taken:&nbsp;"+svLPCStatusPhotos+"</p>";
      emailBody+="<p>Revisit Needed:&nbsp;"+svLPCStatusRevisit+"</p>";
    }
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //DESIGN REVISIT NEEDED SECTION
  if (svDesignRevisitNeeded == "Yes")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>Design Revisit Needed</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>Probe:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitPROBE+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>Structural Revisit:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitSTRUCT+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>Electrical Revisit:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitELEC+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>Plumbing Revisit:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitPLUM+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>Wireless Revisit:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitWIRE+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>Other:&nbsp;"+svWhyRevisitOTHER+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //STRUCTURAL REVIEW
  if (svStructuralReview == "Yes")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>Structural Review</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>Reason:&nbsp;"+svStructuralReviewWhy+"</p>";
    emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }

  //VISIT COMPLETE
  if (svVisitComplete != "")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>Visit Complete</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>"+svVisitComplete+"";
    if (svVisitComplete == "No")
    {
      emailBody+="&nbsp;("+svWhyIncompleteSV+")";
    }
    emailBody+="</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";
  }
  //ACCESS INFO / COMMENTS SECTION
  emailBody+="<h3><u>Access Info and Comments</u></h3>";
  emailBody+="<p>Information Used to access this site:&nbsp;"+svProvideAccessInfo+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p>General Design Visit Comments:&nbsp;"+svComments+"</p>";
  emailBody+="<p>&nbsp;</p>";

  //ZONING HEARING SECTION
  if (svPurpose == "Hearing")
  {
    emailBody+="<h3><u>Zoning Hearing Results</u></h3>";
    emailBody+="<p>"+svHearingResults+"</p>";
  }
  //Logger.Log(emailBody);
  var emailRecipients =   "user@comain.com";
  var emailSubject = "Field Visit Completed for "+svProjectManager+" "+svProjectID;

  // SEND EMAIL //
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    {
      name: svInitials,
      to: emailRecipients,
      subject: emailSubject,
      htmlBody: emailBody
    });
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search)
{
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == search) return i;

  return -1;
}
```